# SQL Server connection works on an test app but not on the actual app

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I made a simple test app to test a SQL Server connection. First I tested a local database and then the actual remote database. Both connections worked fine.

But when I paste this very same code to my actual application then only the local database connection works. Trying to connect to the remote database throws `SqlException` #2

I can't see why the code works on one app but not on another. Any ideas?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim connStr As String = "Server=AAG-SQL02;Database=ProhaDB;Trusted_Connection=True"
        ''Dim connStr As String = "Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=ProhaDB;Trusted_Connection=True"

        Try
            Dim dbConn = New SqlConnection(connStr)
            dbConn.Open()
            dbConn.Close()
            MsgBox("Connection OK")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Exception thrown:

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Can you please also post the **complete and exact** exception message(s) you're getting??

Comment: Exception info added

Comment: This means your connection string isn't correct - you either have a server or a database that's not really present / reachable - or the server you're trying to reach isn't up and running - or some network setting prevents your code from making that connection. Check and double-check your connection string information in great detail!

Comment: Then why does it work in a test app then?

Comment: What's the difference between your 'test app' and your 'actual app'? We don't have much to go on. Different user? Different computer? Different compilation?

Comment: The actual app is an application with about 15000 code lines. Same user, same computer, same session, same time, same compilation settings except build output path. I don't get it. Localhost sql server works fine.

Comment: I did some more testing. If the solution is saved to drive C: it works. But if the solution is saved to a network drive then it doesn't work and SQL connection to a remote database fails. So it might be a VS settings issue, but which one?

Comment: Also built .exe works if it's placed on drive C: but doesn't work if it's on a network drive.

Answer (score 0):

Please allow the user the specific database which you're defined into the database and with same user need to access the db other network error will throw you the same exception always.

Ping the server ip in your cmd and check the server responds to you or not.

open the cmd
just write ping AAG-SQL02

Comment: Yes, AAG-SQL02 responds to ping

Comment: great. make the .exe file and execute into server check the working file with connection, if yes the your remote connection have problem because you doing the good staff.

Comment: .exe also works fine. But on my actual application it doesn't. The code and connection string are exactly the same. This is making me nuts.

Comment: Omg that's thing is totally wired and pathetic